# Eliminate cycle from a digraph by reversing p arcs

Tags: graph-theory

Can anyone help me with this problem or give me a hint about how to solve the problem ?

We consider the street network of a given city. Prove that if we can remove all the cycles in this network by creating at most p blockings (blocking means obstructing one way of a street), then we can remove all the cycles in the city network by reversing one way of at most p streets. (Reversing one way of a given two ways street means to transform it into a one-way-street; reversing an one-way-street means to transform it into the other one-way-street.)

Comment: Just wanted to check in about the terminology. “Creating a blocking” means cutting an edge? And “reversing one way” means reversing an edge? So the theorem here is “if a digraph can be made acyclic by deleting at most p edges, that digraph can also be made acyclic by reversing at most p edges?”

Comment: Yes, the terminology is correct and that is the theorem that I have to prove.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is mainly about programming, not math. Can you please try search answer on your question here - math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set of edges that, if deleted from a digraph, leave it acyclic is called a feedback arc set. So let’s imagine you take the smallest feedback arc set S in the graph (which, we know, has size at most p) and remove it, leaving an acyclic graph.

Now, imagine adding any one individual edge from S back into the DAG that remains. This has to cause a cycle - otherwise, we didn’t need that edge in our feedback set S, and so S wasn’t minimal.

We can then ask - how, exactly, did this cycle arise? Well, since the DAG has a topological ordering, that cycle must occur by following the newly-added edge from some node v in the DAG back to an ancestor u - which appears earlier in the topological ordering than v - and then following some subsequence of nodes from that topological ordering back to v.

Now imagine you add this edge back to the graph, but you do so by adding it back in reverse (from u to v). You can argue that the topological ordering of the old DAG is exactly the same as the new DAG, since u already precedes v in the ordering. That means that you’re left with a DAG, and not only that, but the old topological ordering is still a valid topological ordering of the new DAG!

Because of this, you can repeat this process. Pick another edge from S and add it back it. That causes a cycle, and you can argue that this cycle similarly can be formed by walking from a node to an ancestor in the topological ordering and then walking back. More precisely, at least one of the cycles closed must have been from the DAG formed by removing all of S. Therefore, adding the reverse of that edge back in to the graph won’t result in any cycles because it preserves the topological ordering.

The net effect of this is that if you have a minimal set of edges that can be removed to delete all cycles (say, removing at most p edges), you can instead reverse all those edges to delete all cycles (reversing at most p edges).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot.